# Asus X401A with power but no Display

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I have this Asus X401A Series.  The problem is, when I put-on the pc:

1. Power light indicator is on;
2. Power light indicator for hard disk, it light for a second and it does not continue.  I changed a new hard drive and still the same;
3. Screen is on but no display;
4. No beeps at all.

Please help, it's only a year old PC.

Please view my laptop's problem here. [vimeo.com/84481647](http://vimeo.com/84481647)

Comment: why would you assume the problem was the hard drive?

Comment: I thought was the hard drive because the lights indicating that the hard drive is running, stops on blinking after 2 seconds.  What I did was took off the hard drive, put it in a docker to see if it can be read and unfortunately not, that's why I decided to change it.

Comment: is the laptop over or under 1 year old?

Comment: Yes, it's more than already.

Comment: do you have any usb plugs, plugged into it?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 ports of USB 3.0 plugs

Comment: not what i asked, i asked if anything is plugged into them. of course every laptop has usb plugs =\

Comment: I'm sorry.  Nothing was plug in it.

Comment: Please try to view this if you can.  http://vimeo.com/84481647

Answer (score 0):

[Your laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X401A/#specifications) says it has a 2 year warranty. I would try calling Asus about the problem if it's less than 2 years old, the only thing i can suggestion is your laptop has a TV out functionality, plug it into another monitor to possibly display whats going on.

I don't think it was ever a hard drive issue because if you even remove the hard drive, you will see the screen show display and say there is no operating system found.

That being said, it's most likely a motherboard issue, if the monitor is lighting up, it might mean that it's fine. This is the biggest problem with laptop's, you really can't test anything if something fails. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 on the video, i've seen you post the same problem around the net, hope you find a solution.